# TFS migration - configure features - stream error

Tags: tfs, agile, scrum, tfs-2015

Doing the upgrade from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 (to go after at TFS 2015). No problem during the migration. I'm now at the step to configure features for each project and the verify button give me this error:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: stream

Information that can help figure out the problem. We are using the template "EMC - Scrum for team system" and that template was changed a little for our need. Only have 3 work items for that project.

How can I know what to look for to fix this error?

We want to change the template and use the new Agile template from TFS 2015 at the upgrade is done from TFS 2012 to 2015. How can I change from one template to another one inside a TFS project?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configure features wizard is not going to be able to do its magic on a customised SfTS3 process template so you're going to be configuring features manually.

[Add Features Using a Manual Update Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500409(v=vs.110).aspx)

It will be a reasonable amount of work but can be done.  However, if you plan to migrate to the Agile process (I prefer to use the Scrum process, personally) then you may as well get busy doing that.

Options:

- Create a new project with the Agile template and migrate your Work Items/Code (Excel/Integration Platform/etc.)
- Start bending the SfTS template into the shape of the Agile template

[Migrating Scrum for Team System 3.x to MS Scrum 2.0](http://almsweden.com/magnust/2012/11/02/migrating-scrum-for-team-system-3-x-to-ms-scrum-2-0/) /

[Migrate a TFS project to another process template](http://almsweden.com/magnust/2015/07/06/migrate-a-tfs-project-to-another-process-template/)

Comment: You might find these scripts useful if you are updating your process template. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/02/03/scripts-to-import-and-export-process-templates-from-tfs/